# How do I make a robot (represented by the character 'X') find it's way through a maze using random number generation

Tags: c++, maze

I really need help on this.  I'm trying to create a robot to find it's way out of a maze.  I already created the maze using an array of characters but I literally have no idea how to go about this problem.  I would really like some help please.
I need to implement 3 functions:
• createMaze(char maze[][columns], int columns, int rows) – initializes your maze
• showMaze(char maze[][columns], int columns, int rows) – display maze and robot
• robot(char maze[][columns], int lastColumn, int lastRow, int &nextColumn, int
&nextRow) – robot makes a random move

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

 int main()
{
    char maze [10][10] =
    {   {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',},
        {'*', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ',' ', ' ',' ', ' ',},
        {'*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',},
        {'*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',},
        {'*','*',' ',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*',},
        {'*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',},
        {'*','*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ',},
        {'*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',},
        {'*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ',},
        {'*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*','*',}
    };

    for (int row  = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {
            cout << maze[row][col];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

cout << ================================= << endl;
/*

********** // robot enters from here
*         
** **** **
** * ** **
**  *** **
** ***** *
**   * **   
**** *****
**** **** 
**** *  **
// robot exits here

Program ended with exit code: 0
*/
```

Comment: Could you provide some more parameters to your problem?  Is there a defined entrance/exit point... or does the robot need to find that as well?  Can the robot see the entire maze at once or only the 4 possible directions it can move on any given step?   Is it ok if robot exits the maze using the same portal it entered the maze?

Comment: There's an algorithm detailed in "The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Nighttime". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curious_Incident_of_the_Dog_in_the_Night-Time

Answer (score 1):

People say always follow the wall, eventually you will find the way out. I used to use this way in my code. Start from the beginning and always check what you have around. choose a wall your left hand side or right hand side. Let the character follow the wall. It will find a way out. It is like you start walking by slipping your hand to a wall and you never take your hand off from the wall.

For example in the picture below i put a link. Open the link and start from start point and only follow a wall the left one at the beginning or the right. you will find the way out. I attempted a robot competition like that we were seeking rooms to find something.
https://mathjokes4mathyfolks.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/maze.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the advantage here of knowing the start and end location of the maze. Since you know this you can use the A* search algorithm mentioned here:
https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/solving-mazes-using-python-simple-recursivity-and-a-search/

I used this to solve a maze problem from a Palo Alto Networks challenge earlier this year and it worked well.

I did also try a random walk and it worked to solve the mazes, but this algorithm is much more efficient since you know the environment.